# Why is the type scaled_float in Elasticsearch has "float" in its name?

Tags: elasticsearch

The documentation of Elasticsearch states

> scaled_float
> A floating point number that is backed by a long, scaled by a fixed double scaling factor.

As long is an integer, it sounds to me like a fix-comma number, not a float.

Am I missing something? Is it the recommend type for amounts? (As floats are not to be used)

Answer (score 0):

further down in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/number.html), it says;

> For floating-point types, it is often more efficient to store floating-point data into an integer using a scaling factor, which is what the scaled_float type does under the hood. For instance, a price field could be stored in a scaled_float with a scaling_factor of 100. All APIs would work as if the field was stored as a double, but under the hood Elasticsearch would be working with the number of cents, price*100, which is an integer. This is mostly helpful to save disk space since integers are way easier to compress than floating points. scaled_float is also fine to use in order to trade accuracy for disk space. For instance imagine that you are tracking cpu utilization as a number between 0 and 1. It usually does not matter much whether cpu utilization is 12.7% or 13%, so you could use a scaled_float with a scaling_factor of 100 in order to round cpu utilization to the closest percent in order to save space.

to expand on that example, a price of `$1.10` and a scaling factor of `100` would mean the price is stored as `1.10 * 100`, or `110`, an integer. then when it's read back Elasticsearch will convert the value to it's original by doing the opposite - `110 / 100` to give `1.10`.

also to nit pick, it's Elasticsearch, the s is not camel cased :)

Comment: I corrected the camel case :-)

Comment: Speaking of nitpicking: My question might look just like nitpicking, but I'm very convinced that naming and terminology should be correct. 

The problem is, when you are working with numbers, where you expect a predefined precision (e. g. $ amounts), you never should use float types. Having now the correct type, which is called decimals or fix-comma elsewhere, named ...float is confusing and leads to unnecessary discussion (whether it is the right type or not).

Comment: yep I can appreciate that, naming is generally hard

Comment: Agreed. It's fixed-point, not floating-point.